# déposer à une borne - meaning

Tags: sens

I have heard the following sentence in the TV series Marseille:

> Tu me déposes à un arrêt de bus ou à une borne, s'il te plait.

Context: A girl is taking a ride a with a friend and tells him the sentence above.

What does "borne" mean here? I have looked at https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/borne/10264 and https://www.wordreference.com/fren/borne , but I could not found the meaning of the word in this context.

Answer (score 4):

Étant donné le contexte, ce pourrait être une « station de taxi. »

Comment: So "borse" can be used to refer to a taxi stand (= "station de taxi(s)" in French) ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: We say “Borne d'appel” usualy present at taxi station.

Comment: What is a "borne d'appel" in this context? I only know them as public emergency telephones in the street/road (https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borne_d%E2%80%99appel) .

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: have a look at http://www.taxis-paris.fr/telephone-bornes-taxis.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link. Is this still popular with the advent of Uber and similar mobile apps?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: It still exists, at least in Paris.

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly a ***levélo*** rental station (a bike rental service similar to the Parisian Vélib).

The following picture shows what is called *la borne principale* which is present in every location:

[image]

See http://www.levelo-mpm.fr/Comment-ca-marche/Les-stations

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It'd be nice to include in the answer that levélo is a *bike* rental service.

Comment: By the way, I was in Marseilles last week-end and asked the question there and the answer was unanimously about this *borne*.